# Print numbers in the array into * Eg. 1 into * and 5 into ***** C programming

Tags: c, for-loop

Need help in printing these given numbers into asterisks but I am new to programming; how do I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[5]={20,1,5,15,12};
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop, you could create a loop to output the number of asterisks you need.

Something along these lines:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < a[i]; j++){
        putchar("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: you might want to use `putchar('*');` instead of some non standard `print` function.